# Как передать props в компонент отображаемый при помощи псевдоэлемента 'component'?

Tags: vue.js

Не понимаю, как передать свойства в компонент который отображается при помощи псевдоэлемента 'component'.

Пример:

```
<component :is="ChildComponent">
```

как передать параметр в ChildComponent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас `ChildComponent` это имя компонента, то просто без `:` :

```
<component is="ChildComponent" some_prop="some_value"></component>
```

Comment: Проверил.Работает. Спасибо